# I need python linux dependency on windows machine

Tags: python, linux

I am looking for get python linux dependency on windows machine.

I have Windows and Linux machine, where on Linux machine I don't have admin privilege.
Hence I need to get python dependency on Windows machine and get it manually transfer to linux machine.

For example,
On windows if I run "pip install pyOpenSSL" command, then all dependency for OpenSSL getting download but those dependency are compatible to windows machine.

I am looking for get download dependency for Linux machine on windows box.

Basically, I can not run any command inside Linux box, I can copy pre-compiled python module to execute my code.

On Windows If I run "pip install pyOpenSSL" I am getting few files compatible to windows (_openssl.pyd, _padding.pyd), but on Linux this is expected as .so files.

Note -I can not use Docker or any other virtual machine.

Please let me know if any other solution?

Comment: "where on Linux machine I don't have admin privilege"—what does this have to do with Windows? How would being able to download Linux builds of Python libraries on Windows help if you still don't have admin rights on your Linux machine?

Comment: Why do you think you need admin rights on your Linux machine? If you are using a virtual environment (a best practice) you shouldn't need admin rights.

Comment: Thank you Chris for quick reply- basically can not run any command inside Linux box, updated my question.

Comment: What do you mean by "can not run any command inside Linux box"? Do you have shell access?

Comment: don't have shell access but can copy files. and run through some ui.

Comment: It's possible to run Python as an unprivileged user on Linux, although it needs a bit of set-up so that the Python runtime can find dependencies at runtime. You could obtain a package suitable for your platform from a repository and, rather than installing it using system tools, just unpack it in your home directory. How to unpack it will depend on the package format, among other things. But... how can you do _any_ of this if you can't run any commands on the Linux machine?

Comment: Thank you Kevin,The idea is get download all package on windows and get transfer to Linux and run it, The issue is few files when getting download as windows OS files as mentioned in question.

Comment: There isn't a good solution to this. Ideally, move to another service that gives you basic features like a shell connection. IMO there is no reason whatsoever to use FTP-only hosting in 2020. If that isn't possible for some reason, you'll probably need a very similar machine (same CPU architecture, same operating system, ideally same available libraries, etc.) on which to build your environment. Moving environments is nontrivial.